# Film about man who finds alien orbs on planets

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Best I can remember about movie:

- Man leaves his wife for a 30 year journey to track a signal on another planet.
- The USA races China to get to the planet and it is one guy on a ship with 2 AI computers.

  - One to manage the space ship and the other for the lander.
- He gets to the first planet and finds an orb in a shallow liquid.

  - Then heads to another planet where he finds another on a cliff.
- The Chinese ship is destroyed and he travels to a 3rd planet and finds a 3rd orb.

  - At the 3rd planet he discovers another signal from a planet outside our known galaxy so he travels to it and finds a 4th orb and organic substance (basically, alien life).

What is this movie?

Comment: When did you read it? And can you check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Magellan](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5361488/) (2017). This was on UK TV recently, maybe on SyFy.

> After NASA picks up a trio of mysterious signals from within our own solar system, astronaut Roger Nelson is dispatched on a multi-year solo mission aboard the Magellan spacecraft to investigate the sources.

He leaves his wife, it's a race against China, the ship has AI, he finds 3 orbs on 3 planets and in the end heads to the 4th. The trailer:

Comment: In what way does this match the question asked?

Comment: Added some details to the original answer.